# Setting multiple variable value and perform subtraction in thymleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new in Thymeleaf  and i try to subtract value of column paid amount from total amount but gives error as follow:
[image: error that i get on browser]

and if I comment `Remaining amount` column i get following result: 
[image: if I comment Remaining amount column i get this result]

```
<div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(cust)}">
            <table border="1" style="width: 300px">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Total Amount</th>
                    <th>Paid Amount</th>
                    <th>Remaining Amount</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                <tr th:each="customer : ${cust}">
                    <td th:text="${customer.name}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${customer.address}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${customer.phone}"></td>
                    <td
                        th:with="result1=${#aggregates.sum(customer.customerDetails.![totalAmount])}">
                        <span th:text="${result1}"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td
                        th:with="result3=${#aggregates.sum(customer.payment.![paidAmount])}">
                        <span th:text="${result3}"></span>
                    </td>
                     <td th:with="result=${#aggregates.sum(customer.customerDetails.![totalAmount])}, result2=${#aggregates.sum(customer.payment.![paidAmount])}">
                    <span th:text="${result}- ${result2}"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </th:block>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: check for null values before subtract or let the backend doesnt return null values.

Comment: finally i figured out the problem, i was sending null  value for payment  from controller for customer with id:2, when i assign value of payment for customer 2 ,then it works fine..thanks patrick